# Javascript onchange function not working on select tag

Tags: javascript, html

I made 2 input fields and 1 select field and I applied onchange() function to select tag which calls javascript and that script make calculation and show it in other two fields 
but it is not working for some syntax or logic reasons. please take a look at my code ,any help would be appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function update() {
var x = document.getElementsByName("n_person").value;
document.getElementsByName("m_income").value= x*5;
document.getElementsByName("y_income").value= x*4;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>


<div class="elist"> <span class="b_text"><span>*</span>Level 1:</span>
// here is select tag where I put onchage function  <select class="ifield" name="n_person" onChange="update()">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Choose no. of person referred</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
// These are teh input where resultant value will appear  <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Your weekly Income..." name="m_income" id="weekly_income" class="field" readonly required />
  <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Your day Income..." name="y_income" id="day_income" class="field" readonly required/>
</div>
<!--elist-->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `getElementsByName[0].value` or use `querySelector`

Comment: Whenever you see `getElements..` with an `"s"` it means plural, as in it returns a nodeList, not a single element

Comment: Thanks!! @tushar and Adeneo for pointing out mistake and explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4x7n96da/1/)

**Updated JS**

```
function update() {
  var x = document.getElementsByName("n_person")[0].value;
  document.getElementsByName("m_income")[0].value = x * 5;
  document.getElementsByName("y_income")[0].value = x * 4;
}
```

The problem with your JS was you was not targetting the correct HTML elements using `getElementsByName`.

Please read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName)

Comment: Thanks!! mate , for fixing the code :) query solved !

Comment: Great...glad that it helped.. :)

Answer (score 3):

The method `getElementsByName` returns, as its name indicates, a list of elements with the specified name and not just one. In your case, the names are unique to the document and the method will return a list with just one value, but you'll still need to index this list. Therefore, you must change this:

```
var x = document.getElementsByName("n_person").value;
```

to

```
var x = document.getElementsByName("n_person")[0].value;
```

Do this also for the other uses of `getElementsByName` and your code will work.

Comment: Thanks!!  Alex, you are right , I wasn't using "index" while assigning select options to variable x.